# How to prevent a Ruby method inside a jQuery onclick event from executing on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Ruby method nested inside a jQuery onclick event and I want the method to execute when the div is clicked. This works; however, the method is also executing on page refresh. Why does it also execute on page refresh and is there any way to limit it to only onclick?

```
 $(function() { 
   $('.myDiv').click(function(){
      <% foo_bar %>
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how `foo_bar` can be executed when you click on the div. Ruby is executed server side, jQuery is executed client side. You cannot execute ruby code from your client.
Your `foo_bar` is executed on refresh page because the server need to interpret it to give it's result into the `<% %>` tag. However, when you click on the div, nothing will happen because the jquery function will be empty (since you did not write `<%= %>`). Even if you wrote `<%= %>`, the *jQuery would only execute the `foo_bar` result*, not the function itself.

Maybe you could explain what you want to do in your `foo_bar`. If you want interact with the server, you will need something like `Ajax`.

Answer (score 1):

Please review [this blog entry](http://dgrmm.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/web-application-101/) I wrote.  In short, the ruby code executes on the server, and the javascript, which runs on the client, sees nothing.   To have javascript interact with ruby, you need to initiate a request back to the server via some kind of ajax request.  Libraries like jquery help with this.